# What is the correct way to format data to send by HAL SPI in STM32?

Tags: stm32, spi, eeprom

I am trying to read/write data from ST EEPROM M95640-W

Acording to datasheet, for read operations data command must be formated like:

[image: M95640-W Read operation]

First is 8-bit instruction "Read from Memory Array": **0x03 (B00000011)**

Second is 16-bit address.

But when I send command and data I got this:

**Address 0x0001 (B00000001):**
[image: M95640 Read from address 0x1]

And just to check data position with mirrored bits

**Address 0x0081 (B10000001):**
[image: M95640 Read from address 0x81]

---

So I can not find an error in my code, why it send data in that incorrect way. It send *0x20* command except of *0x03*. It send *0x48* address except of *0x01* and *0x80* except of *0x81*. Looks like I got an incorrect data translation between types uint16_t -> uint8_t*.

So here is the code:

```c
#define EEPROM_SPI   hspi1
#define EEPROM_READ  0x03  // Read from Memory Array

 /**
  * @brief  Reads a block of data from the EEPROM.
  * @param  pBuffer: pointer to the buffer that receives the data read from the EEPROM.
  * @param  ReadAddr: EEPROM's internal address to read from.
  * @param  NumByteToRead: number of bytes to read from the EEPROM.
  * @retval None
  */
uint8_t sEE_ReadBuffer(uint8_t* pBuffer, uint16_t ReadAddr, uint16_t NumByteToRead) {
    /*!< Select the EEPROM: Chip Select low */
    EEPROM_LED_ON();
    EEPROM_CS_LOW();

    /*!< Send "Read from Memory" instruction and MSB of WriteAddr  */
    EEPROM_SendInstruction((uint8_t*)EEPROM_READ, 1);

    /*!< Send WriteAddr address byte to read from */
    EEPROM_SendInstruction((uint8_t*)ReadAddr, 2);

    if (HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&EEPROM_SPI, (uint8_t*)pBuffer, NumByteToRead) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /*!< Deselect the EEPROM: Chip Select high */
    EEPROM_CS_HIGH();
    EEPROM_LED_OFF();

    return 0;
}

void EEPROM_SendInstruction(uint8_t *instruction, uint8_t size) {
    while (EEPROM_SPI.State == HAL_SPI_STATE_RESET) {
        osDelay(1);
    }

    if (HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&EEPROM_SPI, (uint8_t*)instruction, (uint16_t)size) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

SPI initialization:

```c
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void) {
    hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
    hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
    hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
    hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
    hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;

    if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

**UPD1:** I did the packet like @Guillaume Michel said and it worked:
[image: M95640 Read from address 0x81 Working way]

**UPD2** I published the libriary at [Github](https://github.com/firebull/STM32-EEPROM-SPI), writing and reading data is fully functional. Help is welcome to review the code and add some new features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not seem to be written to use DMA, so don't use it. Try to use `HAL_SPI_Receive` and `HAL_SPI_Transmit` rather than `HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA` and `HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA`.

The polarity and the phase seem OK, but double check.

I am not sure that the way you call `EEPROM_SendInstruction` is correct. Try this instead:

```
uint8_t sEE_ReadBuffer(uint8_t* pBuffer, uint16_t ReadAddr, uint16_t NumByteToRead) {

  uint8_t tmpBuf[2];

  /*!< Select the EEPROM: Chip Select low */
  EEPROM_LED_ON();
  EEPROM_CS_LOW();

  /*!< Send "Read from Memory" instruction and MSB of WriteAddr  */
  tmpBuf[0] = EEPROM_READ;
  EEPROM_SendInstruction(tmpBuf, 1);

  /*!< Send WriteAddr address byte to read from */
  tmpBuf[0] = (uint8_t)(ReadAddr<<8);
  tmpBuf[1] = (uint8_t)ReadAddr;
  EEPROM_SendInstruction(tmpBuf, 2);

  if (HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&EEPROM_SPI, (uint8_t*)pBuffer, NumByteToRead) != HAL_OK) {
      Error_Handler();
  }

  /*!< Deselect the EEPROM: Chip Select high */
  EEPROM_CS_HIGH();
  EEPROM_LED_OFF();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I already did the same and that solved the problem. I will update the question with image soon. Thank you!

Comment: Ah. DMA is working, but for now I turned it off, as it is harder to control CS line - it must be turned on and off in interrupts. I will test it later.